# Is it possible to use binding with JavaFX HTMLEditor

Tags: binding, javafx, html-editor

I use `TextArea` in my project and I bidirectionally bind `area.textProperty()` with property of some object. But the text in this area is actually html markup so `HTMLEditor` seems good choice. But I haven't found any way to bind it with property of my object. How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible since `HTMLEditor` doesn't extend [`TextInputControl`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html) and doesn't inherit the [`textProperty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#textProperty--).

Moreover, [`setHtmlText(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/HTMLEditor.html#setHtmlText-java.lang.String-) and [`getHtmlText()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/HTMLEditor.html#getHtmlText--) are the public API's used for setting and getting content from the control. There is no public property present which can be used for binding of text.